# Tizen Input Delegator App-Control deosn't work(Wearable profile/Web Application)

Tags: web, tizen

Tizen provide the input delegator as common app control.

https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/guides/web-application/application-management/application-information-and-controls/application-controls/common-application-controls#inputdelegator

I try to launch input delegator app-control using reference guide code snipet as below.

```
var appControlData = new tizen.ApplicationControlData('http://tizen.org/appcontrol/data/input_type', ['input_voice']);

var appControl = new tizen.ApplicationControl('http://tizen.org/appcontrol/operation/get_input',
                                            null, 'text/plain', null, [appControlData], null);

tizen.application.launchAppControl(appControl, null, function() {
    console.log('launch application control succeed');
}, function(e) {
    console.log('launch application control failed. reason: ' + e.message);
}, null);
```

But the request failed with below error message.

> "launch application control failed. reason: No matched application found."

I tried it on wearable 2.3.2 / 3.0 emulator and Gear Sport target (Tizen 3.0.0.2).
The results were all the same.

How can I use input delegator?
Is not it supported on the device?

Comment: I am getting same error....I hope this has a workaround and someone will post it

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your error on my devices. Then I was able to create an `ApplicationControl` object like this:

```
/** setup image data, basic 4x4 image, encoded base64 
  * (I don't know if this data is a valid parameter. In my test any kind of 
  * input was accepted)
  */
var imagedata1 = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAQAAAAECAYAAACp8Z5+AAAAD0lEQVQYV2NkQAOMpAsAAADuAAUtpgPEAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC";

var imagedata2 = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAQAAAAECAYAAACp8Z5+AAAAD0lEQVQYV2NkQAOMpAsAAADuAAUtpgPEAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC";

var  appControl =
  new tizen.ApplicationControl(
      "http://tizen.org/appcontrol/operation/view",
      null,
      "image/jpeg",
      null,
      [new tizen.ApplicationControlData("images",
          [imagedata1, imagedata2])] );
```

You should be able to just create `ApplicationControlData` the way you already do, then setup `ApplicationControl` as is shown in the code provided.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. `MIME Type` (3rd argument of new tizen.ApplicationControl) should be `null` because App FW does NOT support it **before Tizen 4.0**.

```
var appControl = new tizen.ApplicationControl('http://tizen.org/appcontrol/operation/get_input',
                                        null, null, null, [appControlData], null);
//text/plain should be removed
//var appControl = new tizen.ApplicationControl('http://tizen.org/appcontrol/operation/get_input',
                                        null, text/plain, null, [appControlData], null);
```

and, If you want keyboard input, use `input_keyboard` as below

```
var appControlData = new tizen.ApplicationControlData('http://tizen.org/appcontrol/data/input_type', ['input_keyboard']);
```

**I tested and verified it on tizen 2.3.2 emulator and Gear Sport(Tizen 3.0)**

May the force be with you.